# How do I delete duplicate information on the output log in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scripting, windows-server

Hi I'm am really new to the Powershell scene, currently I am working on a simple task related to IIS, where I have to retrieve every "information" event and write it to a file.

Thing is, it writes a lot of repeated info and I want it to write only the most recent events

here's the original output:

**20/05/2020 16:49:09  Application-Info STARTED**

**Filtering 'Information/Warning Levels' related to IIS**

**Provider Name:** Microsoft-Windows-WAS

**Time Created **     : 12/05/2020 14:57:20
**Id **              : 5186
**LevelDisplayName** : Information

**TimeCreated**      : 12/05/2020 10:42:36
**Id**               : 5186
**LevelDisplayName** : Information

**TimeCreated**      : 08/05/2020 15:18:07
**Id**               : 5186
**LevelDisplayName** : Information

**TimeCreated**      : 08/05/2020 10:57:38
**Id**               : 5186
**LevelDisplayName** : Information

**TimeCreated**      : 07/05/2020 20:20:54
**Id**               : 5211
**LevelDisplayName** : Information

here's the PS script:

```
Clear-Host
Remove-Item E:\www\EvApp_Info_Logs\Application-info*.txt
$log = "E:\www\EvApp_Info_Logs\Application-info-$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm).txt"

$(Get-Date).ToString() + "  Application-Info STARTED" | out-file -FilePath $log -Append

"Filtering 'Information/Warning Levels' related to IIS" | out-file -FilePath $log -Append

Get-WinEvent -FilterXml ([xml](Get-Content C:\WEBIIS-content-information.xml))| 
fl -GroupBy ProviderName -Property TimeCreated, Id, LevelDisplayName | 
Out-File -FilePath $log -Append

$(Get-Date).ToString() + "  Application-Info ENDED" | out-file -FilePath $log  -Append
```

If I use the "get-unique" cmdlet right after

"Get-WinEvent -FilterXml ([xml](Get-Content C:\WEBIIS-content-information.xml))| 
fl -GroupBy ProviderName -Property TimeCreated, Id, LevelDisplayName, Message | get-unique"

it writes only the latest info related to every ProviderName, ignoring the rest of the EventId's.

What I want is for the script to ignore repeated EventId's so the output can look like this:

**20/05/2020 16:49:09  Application-Info STARTED**

**Filtering 'Information/Warning Levels' related to IIS**

**ProviderName:** Microsoft-Windows-WAS

**TimeCreated **     : 12/05/2020 14:57:20
**Id **              : 5186
**LevelDisplayName** : Information

**TimeCreated**      : 07/05/2020 20:20:54
**Id**               : 5211
**LevelDisplayName** : Information

Once again I'm really new in this, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this work for you? $d=Get-WinEvent -FilterXml $filter ; 
$d | Sort-Object -Property id -Unique | fl -GroupBy ProviderName -Property TimeCreated, Id, LevelDisplayName, Message

Comment: Thanks everyone, @Paxz your solution didn't worked for me.

Comment: @Ketanbhut yours worked but the answer given below was more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, fl requires a sorted list. Also, we use Sort-Object to group by (ProviderName and) Id to eliminate duplicates on other properties.

```
    $list | Sort-Object ProviderName, Id -Unique | fl -GroupBy ProviderName -Property TimeCreated, Id, LevelDisplayName
```